# WPF xaml: How to validate Cells in DataGrid with automatically generated Columns

Tags: c#, wpf, validation, xaml, datagrid

How can I add cell validation in an automatically generated DataGrid (from DataTable) and style the cell red if the value is not valid?

This is my DataGrid:

```
    <DataGrid Grid.Row="2"
              Margin="5"
              Background="Transparent"
              MaxHeight="300"
              MaxWidth="500"
              ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True"
              HorizontalAlignment="Center"
              VerticalAlignment="Center"
              ItemsSource="{Binding DataTable}"
              HeadersVisibility="None"
              CellStyle="{StaticResource tableCellTheme}"
              CanUserAddRows="False">
```

I also added

```
        <DataGrid.RowValidationRules>
            <validation:DataGridValidation ValidationStep="UpdatedValue" />
        </DataGrid.RowValidationRules>
```

But I do not want to evaluate the whole row and more importantly, I don't know how to style the offending cell red if this returns false...
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must handle the `DataGrid.AutoGeneratingColumn` event, obtain the reference to the column's binding and then enable binding validation and attach the `ValidationRule` to it:

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<DataGrid AutoGeneratingColumn="EnableCellValidation_OnAutoGeneratingColumn" />
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
private void EnableCellValidation_OnAutoGeneratingColumn(object sender, DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.Column is DataGridBoundColumn column)
  {
    var columnBinding = column.Binding as Binding;
    columnBinding.ValidatesOnDataErrors = true;
    columnBinding.ValidationRules.Add(new DataGridValidation());
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this helped me! However,. the validation only works when entering numbers, if I enter characters the validation method is not called. Do you know why? Respectively, how to resolve this? 
Also, on my diagonal I have text instead of row and column names (as my datatable is symmetrical). Can I set these individual cells to non-editable? Thanks for your help! 

P.s. from where did you learn this stuff? It's easy to find good resources for c#, but somehow I'm struggling with learning xaml......

Comment: Binding validation does not detect the input. Therefore, it does not differentiate between numeric and alphabetic input. The input is simply passed to the ValidationRule.Validate method. You must check the implementation of the rule if it does not perform as expected. To prevent particular cells from being editable you must handle the `DataGrid.BeginningEdit` event and set the event args object to cancelled to avoid entering the edit mode.

Comment: Find yourself a small project. This is the best way to apply what you have learned from reading. You will also run into problems that when solved advance your knowledge (experience).